# Can I be able to show a static message below as a dropdown in the textinput in react-native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I need to show a static message while typing an input or if the user focuses on the TextInput in react-native.

I need to show the Input field must contain the following letters.

How can I show this below the box in a floating manner, not inside the view of the screen in react-native

```js
<TextInput>
    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
    secureTextEntry={this.state.passwordDisplayed}
    textContentType="password"
    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ password: text })}
    bluronSubmit={true}
    placeholderTextColor={'grey'}
    placeholder={'Password'}
</TextInput>
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native's TextInput does not have a prop for showing an arbitrary message, but you can do this by creating a custom component that has both your text input and the message, and controlling when the message is shown by observing your text input focus.

To show the message as 'floating' outside of your input's bounds, position it as 'absolute' and add a top margin equal to the input height. You can use `onLayout` callback to read your input's size:

```
const TextInputWithMessage = ({ message, ...textInputProps }) => {
  const [showMessage, setShowMessage] = useState(false);
  const [inputHeight, setInputHeight] = useState(0);

  return (
    <View onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => setInputHeight(nativeEvent.layout.height)}>
      <TextInput 
        {...textInputProps}
        onFocus={() => setShowMessage(true)}
        onBlur={() => setShowMessage(false)}
      />
      {showMessage && <Text style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, top: inputHeight }}>{message}</Text>}
    <View>
  )
}
```

Note that this will override any `onFocus` and `onBlur` callback you pass in `textInputProps`. If you need some custom behaviour there, you could preserve it like so:

```
onFocus={e => {
  setShowMessage(true);
  if (textInputProps.onFocus) textInputProps.onFocus(e);
}}
```

Omitted for brevity.